# Disable HDD (without deleting the files) in WIN 10? (Sound localization)

Tags: hard-drive

I want to disable/power-off my non-os 3.5" HDD to localize if it's making a sound problem, or if it's something else.

(I have a rising

Comment: Could you not just unplug it/take it out of your machine?

Comment: To amplify @NiallJones' comment, make sure you shut down fully: in the default Win10 settings shut down hibernates. If you don't want to change settings, do a restart and power off when the UEFI/BIOS screen appears. After disconnecting the drive do not boot Windows, as the drive letters may be reassigned; instead, go into the UEFI/BIOS and check for drive sounds from there.

Comment: A rising what? A rising covfefe?

Answer (score 0):

1. Power down your machine.
2. Unplug the power cord from the power supply.
3. Open the case cover.
4. Find the HDD
5. Look for wire that is coming from the power supply to the HDD.
6. Pull out the power plug from the HDD.
7. Put the external power cord back into the power supply.
8. Power up the machine and test.

Bonus alternate step: if your HDD is making too much noise in general, consider swapping to an SSD. They are very quiet. You can buy an external device online that allows you to plug two hard drives into it so you can copy everything from one to another

Comment: The device you mention in bonus paragraph is called "a computer". There's a lot of free and paid software that will do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

One of these should generally work (i.e. request the disk to spin down):

- In Disk Manager (diskmgmt.msc), on the bottom panel, right-click on the "Disk 1" header and select "Offline".
- In Device Manager (devmgmt.msc), right-click on the IDE/SATA/SCSI device and select "Disable".